# django-allauth redirects to a weird page before third part login

Tags: django

I'm using django-allauth to provide login with google accounts. When I click to login with Google, I'm sent to a page of alert that I'm about to use a third part account. This page will scare many users if left untouched. How can I skip this page or, at least be able to edit this page so it become more user friendly?

[image]

My url file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pairs_trading.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

My template file looks like this:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">
```

My settings.py file looks like this:

```
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'pairs_trading.apps.PairsTradingConfig',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google'
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Thanks for any suggestions that may help!